# Bash: how does 'sort' sort paths?

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, unix

How does `sort` work? I have this file:

```
/test# cat foobar
html/lib/ORM/aaa.php
html/lib/ORMBase/ormbase_aaa.php
html/lib/ORM/zzz.php
html/lib/ORMBase/ormbase_zzz.php
```

And this is the output of `sort`:

```
/test# cat foobar | sort
html/lib/ORM/aaa.php
html/lib/ORMBase/ormbase_aaa.php
html/lib/ORMBase/ormbase_zzz.php
html/lib/ORM/zzz.php
```

I tried a lot of options: `-f`, `-i`, `-t/`... and I dont get it. I want to understand why sort thinks this is sorted.

---

NB: It works fine with this other sample:

```
/test# cat foobar2
a/a/a
a/ab/a
a/ab/b
a/a/ab
a/abc/a

/test# cat foobar2 | sort
a/a/a
a/a/ab
a/ab/a
a/ab/b
a/abc/a
```

Comment: what is `a` in `cat a | sort`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sort` tries to be clever with regard to localization. It ignores some non-alphanumeric characters like `/` and so on. The man page has a short sentence on that:

> *** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.

So, to fix your issue:

```
$ cat foobar | LC_ALL=C sort
```

Comment: @KarolyHorvath thanks! I noticed myself and corrected it meanwhile.

Comment: Well, that's perfect, and i learn something ! Thanks a lot :) Worst part is I actually read the man page before asking, but not this part... My bad.

Comment: No problem. Despite the "Warning" it's actually easy to miss (especially the consequences of the setting).